# Inverse Kinematics Documentation

Tags: python, interface, inverse-kinematics, documentation

I am currently writing a thesis and for the practical part I use blender to simulate something with the Blender IK Solver ( and iTaSC).
Are there books etc about the implementation or the usage of the Blender IK Solver/iTAsC available?

I could only find the Blender documentation.

Comment: Since Blender is OpenSource, why not look into the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any books on this specific to blender.

Developers rarely write books on the details of particular implementations, and for blender, any implementation documentation outside the code base will most likely be found on the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/GameEngine/RobotIKSolver). Details of techniques and algorithms are generally best studied from the original paper(s).

As mentioned, blender is open source, so you can read the [source code in git](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/) yourself.

Skimming it, it looks like the wiki is actually fairly detailed here. It also mentions the original paper which may be helpful, if you have access.

Since iTAsC was originally designed for robot control systems, you may want to look at literature in that area.